# fql getting friends of friends list error

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT uid,name FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=582312312)
```

and here is the error:

(NoIndexFunctionException - #604) Can't lookup all friends of 582312312 due to user's privacy settings.

thank You for help.

Answer (score 0):

That is the spec and limitation of the API. To get the result of your FQL, you have to be a friend of `582312312` and have a permission to access the list of his friends.

Comment: Ask him/her to use and auth your app. It's 582312312's matter.